# load content dynamically from listview to another activity

Tags: android, json, api, listview

Android newbie here.

The scenario

I am using my website's api to populate data for Android `ListView`
for the first screen it is called `GameFragment`. Game fragment loads the games from my website [url](http://www.gamerzwiki.com/api/games.json)
I was able to successfully list all games. So my next step would be to show all articles related to the game when user clicks on the game. Using my websites api http://www.gamerzwiki.com/api/news.json?game_id=qwert133 (whatever the id of the item is)

Loading Contents from url

```
try {
        JSONArray games = gp.loadGamesFromApi();
        ArrayList<Games> listData = new ArrayList<Games>();

        if(games != null){
            for(int x = 0 ; x<games.length() ; x++){
                JSONObject game = games.getJSONObject(x);
                try {
                    Games game1 = new Games();
                    game1.title=game.getString("title");
                    game1.id = game.getInt("id");
                    listData.add(game1);
                    //free game 1
                    game1 = null;
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        ArrayAdapter<Games> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Games>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listData);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

so I have a listener

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Object item = l.getSelectedItem();

    Toast.makeText((Context)getActivity(),item.title.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), NewsActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

but it seems I can't get the attribute of the item

but I don't know how I can do that on my `ListView`. So I would like to ask your expert advise

Comment: do you want call second url with game id ?

Comment: yes2.. so I want to attach gameid to every item in listview

Comment: get gamedi using onItemClick listener and pass that id to another activity using intent

Comment: ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listData);

now using this, listData contains string only. How can I attach game id?

Comment: get game id as string

Comment: I edited my question and added the listener @mohan

Comment: set invisible textview on listview and place game id on there and you can easily get game id during onclick

Comment: and u can pass it through the intent like this  intent.putextra("GameId",GameIDTXT.getText().toString())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can do is implement onClick listener on your listview which has all the games:-

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>adapter,View v, int position){

 Games game = adapter.getItem(position);

 Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this,destinationActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("id",game.id);
 startActivity(intent);

  }
 });
```

in your other activity retrieve this as:-

```
String id=getIntent.getStringExtra("id");
```

and now you can use this id to make webservice call in your activity,here ItemClicked is your model class which your are using to populate your listview with your all games

Comment: you need to pass the object to the activity or fragment hosting the listview not to the listview  but from your webservice i think you only need id to get the items for a game so why you want to pass the whole object

Comment: hmm I don't get it sorry I'm so noob. can you give me an example?

Comment: in your second activity you will get get string id as game id as you passed it from this activity on listview on click now in your second activity you can call the webservice with url as,String url= "http://www.gamerzwiki.com/api/news.json?game_id="+id;

Comment: now use this url to make webservice call to get your game items for this particular game and populate the game items listviews with the response you get from this webservice

Comment: I edited my question and added the listener. Parent Class by the way is ListFragment

Comment: do your object item contains the id of the game

Comment: i read your comment above your listdata does not contain id of the game implement the listview with custom adapter

Comment: thanks! so i need to create a custom adapter at first? can you check my question again? I added the code where I set an adapter

Comment: Pramod I think I really need to create a custom adapter since `arrayAdapter` accepts string only. I like your answer though but its better to get the object directly from listview without having to create a new Games object again right? I'll give you an upvote.

Comment: thats what i told you,you have to create a custom adapter class of your own extending arrayadapter or baseadapter you can't pass multiple values to simplearrayadapter you can only pass name or id not both for that you have to implement a custom adapter

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data between activities by using putExtra in the intent

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Games item = adapter.getItem(position);

    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), NewsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("id", item.id);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

In your receiving activity do this

```
String id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
```

You can pass basic datatypes through putExtra. If you want to pass custom objects you'll have to implement Parcelable http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html